# Handlebars error in React: Missing helper: "__html:"

Tags: reactjs, handlebars.js

I have the following template defined as a string variable in my React app:

```
const defaultTemplate = `
  ...
  {{#each articles}}
    <div className="article">
      <strong className="article-title">{{ Title }}</strong>
      <p dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: Description }} />
      Read more: <a href={{ Link }}>{{ Link }}</a>
    </div>
    <br />
  {{/each}}
`;
```

When compiling this template I get the error: `Missing helper: "__html:"`

I'm sure this is some kind of interaction between React and the double curly braces after `dangerouslySetInnerHTML=`, but I don't know how to resolve it.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Why are you using handlebars with react? Handlebars doesn't know what to do with jsx. If you're looping over an array, just use `.map` with react

Comment: I’m allowing my users to create Handlebars templates. My app is compiling them in the browser. Should I be using a different templating library that’s more React-friendly?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just let them write react code directly?

Comment: It looks like you are producing JSX from Handlebars templates? It seems like an odd design to me. However, to answer your question, you would need to escape the `{{ __html: Description }}` that you want Handlebars to ignore. You can do this by adding a couple of backslashes: `dangerouslySetInnerHTML=\\{{ __html: Description }}`. See: https://jsfiddle.net/76484/gtzsxv8r/

Comment: @76484 I agree it's a bit unusual. My app allows my users to create newsletters. These newsletters can use templates to pull in variables, which is what I'm using Handbars for. Perhaps if Handlebars used a different delimiter, it would be less confusing.

Comment: @Samathingamajig My users are not developers. Handlebars templates are already more complex than they can handle.